# Is there a documentation generator for full websites?

Tags: php, javascript, documentation

I just finished writing most of a large intranet website for a company, but now I am tasked with documenting all of it. I see a lot of documentation generators for php, js, etc, but I am not seeing anything that tackles the challenge of documenting a full website. Specifically, I am looking for something that would link a php page to its corresponding css,js, and perhaps the other way around.

Another way of putting it is, what does everyone else use to document full website?

Comment: The "documentors" you see parse code for specially formatted comments and create documentation about the code itself, not what features it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full websites tend to vary on a per-case basis most often. You could code your own documentation generator to suit your exact needs, or if you just want a documentation of your PHP functions then you could use something like [phpdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/), but there's no existing documentation generator that I know of which does exactly what you want.

The problem is that since PHP is dynamic, you'd probably be best off scraping the output HTML for css files rather than looking through the php source.